# Regex for at least 10 alphanumeric characters that contain at least 3 digits

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to build a regex that allows only strings with at least 10 alphanumeric characters that contain at least 3 digits.

For example  :

```
X6JV2YUW8T => True
JN1H86LEKA => True
111JEJE134 => True
A111111111 => True
ABCDEFGHIJ => False
0123456789 => False
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why is the last one `False`?

Comment: _“I'm trying to build a regex”_ - well, there’s your problem. Checks like that (“at least x amount of y”) should not be done using regex in the first place.

Comment: @Phylogenesis My guess is he wants it to be numbers + letters, not just numbers.

Comment: @revilheart I realise that was probably what was needed. It was supposed to be a pointer to the OP that they really cannot do what they want without working out what their rules *actually* are.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, as revilheart  said I want it to be numbers+letters. not just numbers. Sorry for the bad explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want at least 10 alphanumeric characters (characters and digits), and at least 3 digits you could use 2 positive [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for 3 digits and one alphanumeric character (using the case insensitive flag `/i` in the js pattern):

[`^(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z]))(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[0-9]){3})[a-z0-9]{10,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/QslCs0/1/)

That would match:

- `^` Begin of the string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capturing group
  - `[a-z0-9]*[a-z]` Match zero or more alphanumeric characters, then 1 alphanumeric character
  - `)`Close no capturing group
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:[a-z0-9]*[0-9]){3}` Match zero or more alphanumeric characters, then 3 times a digit
- `)` Close lookahaed
- `[a-z0-9]{10,}` Match at least 10 times a alphanumeric character
- `$` End of the string

```js
const strings = [
  "X6JV2YUW8T",
  "JN1H86LEKA",
  "111JEJE134",
  "A111111111",
  "ABCDEFGHIJ",
  "0123456789"
];
const pattern = /^(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z]))(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[0-9]){3})[a-z0-9]{10,}$/i;

strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(s + " :" + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^(?=(.*\d){3})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}$`.

```
^                                             $     The whole string
 (?=(.*\d){3})                                      Should contain at least three digits
              (?=(.*[a-zA-Z]))                      And contain at least one letter
                              [a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}      And be at least 10 alphanumeric characters
```

```js
const examples = [
    'X6JV2YUW8T',
    'JN1H86LEKA',
    '111JEJE134',
    'A111111111',
    'ABCDEFGHIJ',
    '0123456789',
];

const regex = /^(?=(.*\d){3})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}$/;

examples.forEach(example => {
    console.log(`${example} => ${regex.test(example)}`)
});
```

Note: the last one returns true, since it matches the expected syntax based on the question.

Comment: as @revilheart said previously, I want it to be numbers+letters. not just numbers. Sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: @HKHAIT: No problem, answer fixed.